# В WordPress под футером выводится /public_html. Почему? И как убрать?

Tags: wordpress, безопасность, веб-сервер

Делаю сайт на *Wordpress*. Всё работает, проблем вроде нет, но браузер выводит под футером `/public_html`, и меня это немного напрягает, так ведь не должно быть.

[image: браузер выводит под футером "/public_html"]

Браузер *Яндекс*.

Есть ещё одна особенность. Так это работает в *Яндекс* браузере. В *Firefox*, *Google Chrome*, *Microsoft Edge* и мобильном *Яндекс* браузере `/public_html` под футером не отображается, зато отображается отступ от нижней границы экрана, то есть футер откреплен от неё.

[image: отображается отступ от нижней границы экрана]

Связано ли это как то с `/public_html` и как это можно исправить?

P.S. Ещё браузеры показывают, что у меня не защищённое соединение. Может и это имеет значение?

Comment: Показывай сайт. `не защищённое соединение` - это фикция. Обман от гуглохрома.

Comment: woodmade.com.ua

Comment: не совсем понял, какой смысл в этой фикции для гуглхрома?..

Comment: Смысл (для гугла) простой - деньги. Обманывая таким образом пользователей и недалёких вемастеров гугл подсаживает "на иглу" и отнимает деньги. Именно отнимает, язык не поворачивается сказать "зарабатывает". Это чистейшей воды мошейничесво.

Comment: ссылка на сайт woodmade.com.ua

Comment: извиняюсь, а нельзя ли подробнее про "Обманывая таким образом пользователей и недалёких вемастеров гугл подсаживает "на иглу" и отнимает деньги.". Каким ТАКИМ образом? на какую "иглу" ? И что за деньги он отнимает?

Comment: это наверное уже не по теме, так что если что пришлите ответ на почту, если возможно - jonny125@i.ua

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден и он до смешного элементарен. Просто в файле footer.php, у меня каким-то образом оказалась прописана строка /public_html после закрывающего тега `</html>`. Я удалил эту строку в редакторе и всё стало на свои места.